# Exec() command and script flow

Tags: php, exec

I'm just not sure... Does a script with exec(....) wait until the exec() is complete before continuing?

for instance my script will flow like this....

1. Copy PDF file from AWS to web server
2. Convert PDF file to JPG (exec())
3. Upload JPG to AWS
4. Delete both files from server.

Repeat 10,000 times...

Do i need to write something to halt the code until the exec is complete? or can use the exec command, move the files, then delete the files? My concern is the program will try to delete the files before they are converted.

I hope this is clear and thanks...

Comment: PHP generally follows a strictly synchronous approach. However what you _should_ think about is that chaining 10 000 of such coverions and uploads is a questionable thing. You should instead queue those tasks to "jobs" controlled by a "job queuing system". That will be much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `exec()` (if you are talking about system call) is a blocking call, hence further execution of script (whatever language it is !) will be blocked.
You can use `&` and redirect Stderr/Stdout to /dev/null, for running process in background and wait for to complete.

Best way would be do it asynchronously  :

```
fork() --- Child Process
if fork returns 0 
 exec() --- Command you want to process your jpegs with
in parent wait() for exec to complete
```

Answer (score 0):

from the php doc:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> Note:
>
> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
> continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
> redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
> cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

If you are in a loop, and you want to delete files after, why not delete files after the end of the loop (if you have enough storage)

You can also monitor the return of the 3 action, and delete when you are sure that the file are uploaded.

The symfony component process, can help you manage this flow http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks Nicolas.  The line is -- exec("convert -density 100x100 -quality 60 -compress jpeg 3.pdf 3.jpg"); -- so the command IS outputting to file (10,000 times).  This is a test site for me - therefore the EC2 instance is small - it couldn't handle them all.  Though - perhaps i could create a CRONE job to run every 20 minutes or something to rune the conversion on 20-30 files perhaps.

Comment: you need to handle the conversion with php ? 
I mean do you need user data input ?  
If not, you can do a little bash script executed with a cron without involve php